# Shopify Storefront createCustomer does not set phone number

Tags: flutter, dart, shopify, shopify-storefront-api

I am trying to call the Shopify `storefront` GraphQL to create a customer. The customer is being created successfully. However, it does not set the phone number provided for the mutation.

Mutation:

```
const String customerCreateMutation = r''' 
mutation MyMutation($firstName: String, $lastName: String, $email: String!, $password: String!) {
  customerCreate(input: {firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName, email: $email, password: $password}) {
    customer{
      acceptsMarketing
      createdAt
      tags
      displayName
      email
      firstName
      id
      lastName
      phone
   }
  customerUserErrors {
      code
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
''';
```

Graphql:

```
final MutationOptions _options = MutationOptions(
      document: gql(customerCreateMutation),
      variables: {
        'firstName': "john",
        'lastName':"doe",
        'email':"john@gmail.com",
        'password': "password",
        'acceptsMarketing': false,
        'phone': "9876543211", /// tried as "+919876543211" too
      },
    );
final QueryResult result = await _graphQLClient!.mutate(_options);
```

When I print the customer in the result, I get as `result.data['customerCreate']['customer']`, i ma getting the phone as null.

```
{__typename: Customer, acceptsMarketing: false, createdAt: 2023-10-19T12:56:35Z, tags: [], displayName: asdasd asdasd, email: as9@asdasdad.asd, firstName: asdasd, id: ********, lastName: asdasd, phone: null, lastIncompleteCheckout: null}
```

Here, it is sending back the phone as null.

I have checked the created customer in the Shopify store also. But it is also blank.

How do I set the phone number of the customer?
Is there any other way?

Comment: I think you are missing to pass phone in mutation definition, kindly check my answer i revised it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shopify storefront GraphQL API uses `E.164 standard.` for phone number in `customerCreate` mutation

means you need to add `[+] [country code] [number]` then it will accept the phone number.

try adding `+91`

```
+919876543211
```

### I think you missed to pass the `phone` variable in your mutation definition

```
// OLD missing phone variable
mutation MyMutation($firstName: String, $lastName: String, $email: String!, $password: String!) {
  customerCreate(input: {firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName, email: $email, password: $password}) {

// ADD phone variable indefinition
mutation MyMutation($firstName: String, $lastName: String, $email: String!, $phone: String, $password: String!) {
                                                                         HERE ^
  customerCreate(input: {firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName, email: $email, phone: $phone, password: $password}) {
                                                                                  HERE ^
```

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: tried that too. still phone is not getting saved,

Comment: add phone variable to definition and try again, now it should work fine.

Comment: My Silly mistake. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: It happens, I hope now its working fine 